# when clicking on page after closing a window opened via window.open the window reopens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following to open a new window:

```
var win = window.open('URL HERE' , type ,'width=1100,height=500,left=200,top=200');
```

The reason I assign a variable to it is because it allows me to do other things with the variable such as actions on close (which I am not using in this case).

The window opens just fine.  I can do everything I need to do inside the window.  But the problem occurs when I close the window: The window closes but reopens automatically when i click anywhere on the parent page.

This happens if I click the browsers "x" on the new window, or even if I click a link that that includes `onclick="window.close()"`, and it happens every single time I try this.  It's not sporadic at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please just write your question in normal text unless text decoration is absolutely necessary. People can read, you don't need to put several paragraphs in italics and bold. That said: [where is the rest of your code?](/help/how-to-ask) Is `win` referenced anywhere else?

Comment: Where is the window.open call in the original page?  Any chance it's part of an onClick handler?

Comment: You need to show us more of your code - for example, at what juncture is the `var win = window.open()` code executed? What happens to make that code run?

Comment: I've got a select dropdown that has an onchange event handler that runs the open window based on the selection.  Didn't even think about posting that.  Give me a second and I will update code.

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - what a proper [mre] looks like. _“The window closes but reopens automatically when i click anywhere on the parent page.”_ - well maybe the parent page has click handlers that trigger this, we can’t possibly know with the info you have given so far. Edit: A change event handler could possibly also fire when you not expect it, for example if the field loses focus by your “clicking elsewhere in the page” …

Comment: Thats probably whats happening.  When I refocus the page it fires again.  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: _“Any way to avoid that?”_ - probably. But MRE of what exactly you are doing first, please.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

**Avoid using `onchange` and `onblur` together - even though some people post that this fixes some `onchange` problems that occur on ios devices.**

At some point in the past I was dealing with an issue with iphone and ipad not opening a window when running an `onchange` event.  Everyone kept posting about using `onblur` events on those devices.  That didn't fix the problem but I had left an `onchange` and an `onblur` event inside the select dropdown by accident not realizing that was what it was doing.

What was happening was that I was running the `window.open` when the selection changed, and then it was rerunning `window.open` when the window lost focus which resulted in another window opening when refocusing parent page.